# Is there a way to make svg icon adapt to apple system fonts?

Tags: ios, svg, material-ui, accessibility, system-font

Consider the following simple React / MaterialUI component

```
<div>
  <MenuIcon />
  <span style={{ font: '-apple-system-body' }}>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Result of this on my iPhone is attached. As I change the `Settings > Accessibility > Larger Text` option on my iPhone, the `Hello World` text resizes itself. The icon, however, doesnt. Is there a way to make the icon resize too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <span style={{ font: '-apple-system-body' }}>
    <MenuIcon style={{ fontSize: 'inherit', transform: 'scale(1.5)' }}/>
  </span>
  <span style={{ font: '-apple-system-body' }}>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

I noticed that `<MenuIcon>` sets `font-size:1.5rem` by default. Hence, `<MenuIcon style={{ fontSize: 'inherit' }}/>` undid this, and adding `transform: scale(1.5)` made up for the smaller svg size. Further, I had to set the container of the icon to the `-apple-system-body` for the container to respond to changed text-size in the accessibility settings.